# How make POST request in funtions parse-server

Tags: node.js, post, postman, parse-server

I have a function on parse server and I need to test it

When I am going to test the function with POSTMAN it gives me the following error

> {"code": 141, "error": "Invalid function."}

I hope for a positive result

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide mor informations of you curent problem. What kind of response do you expect? How does your request look like? How does your test-code look like?

Comment: Can you please share the code of your function and how you are calling it in POSTMAN? You should do something according to this: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#cloud-code